# Macbook pro late 2011 cannot access windows based server through VPN

Tags: mac, network, wifi, windows, vpn

I am trying to use vpn to access a Windows based server. I set up the VPN when I was at the office, and was able to connect when I was connected to the internet at the office through VPN, but as soon as I went home, I tried it and it did not work.

I have no idea what I am doing wrong I even read to send all traffic through the VPN and tried that and it didn't work.

Is it possible to access VPN with a Mac into a Windows based server.

Comment: There are standardized VPN protocols (you can select those on setup). If you enter all the credentials correctly there is no reason why it shouldn't work. Any specific error message?

Answer (score 1):

When you were at the office, did you use a ***different*** network like a AT&T/Verizon/Sprint hotspot?  Next time, try testing at a Starbucks or another public wifi first.

More than likely the VPN server dosen't allow loop backs (meaning you are in the network to start, go out, to come back in).  It probably just connected you.

What VPN (server) are you using?  What error message did you get?

In my past experiences, I have found that SSL VPNs are the way to go especially with Macs.